# Advises to recover my wallet

Tags: wallets, password, recovery, keystore

I got a wallet from https://www.myetherwallet.com/ and then I downloaded all the files (keystore, qr.pdf and private key). Then I compressed (zip) these files using a password I can't remember (yes, that's stupid).

So basically I have the public key, the name of the keystore file and the password of the keystore file. What would you recommend to recover the private key ?

So far I tried fcrackzip with a dictionary of passwords I usually use. But no success... I wonder if there might be another way of recovering these files.

Comment: Can you download the wallet from MEW again?

Comment: How could I do that ?

Comment: I guess you can't. Have you imported the wallet into other ethereum clients?

Comment: No... I was hoping that with the current information I had I could recover the wallet

Answer (score 1):

I would write this in the comments, but I can't yet because I don't have 50 rep yet, so "an answer" it is!

Do you remember anything about your password? That would greatly improve your chances of recovering the funds. You could create a custom word list tailored to what you remember.

You can use [John The Ripper Jumbo](http://www.openwall.com/john/) (actually a community edition of the software) which supports cracking password protected ZIPs.

This is going to be a process that requires knowledge (working with command line tools, a lot of googling) and a ton of CPU/GPU power.

Comment: Thx, I tried building my own zip cracker in python but it seems that I used a really strong and unusual password.. Thanks for the link btw

Comment: @debzsud Be aware that sending the compressed zip file to that eric may allow him to steal your money.